How can I prevent postgres from automatically creating multiple similar indexes named <my index names>_ccnew?
I've noticed recently that after reindexing my tables, I end up with a set o new indexes which seem to have been automatically created by postgres. In the DDL below, all the indexes ending in _ccnew(#) are created by postgres.
How can I instruct postgres to stop creating these indexes ? They just end up taking a lot of space plus at times, when I try to reindex, I get errors complaining that a _ccnew index cannot be recreated or it doesn't exist.
If I remove them, after a new reindexing they show up again
To reindex, I've tried both

REINDEX TABLE CONCURRENTLY ${tableName};

and

REINDEX TABLE ${tableName};

In both cases I was seeing the same postgres behavior
I run a Postgres 16 DB on debian. Container name is : groonga/pgroonga:3.2.0-debian-16
Any ideas?
Thanks
CREATE TABLE "search".ar (
    id uuid NOT NULL,
    product_id uuid NOT NULL,
    "text" text NULL,
    username varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    creation_time timestamp NOT NULL,
    update_time timestamp NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT search_ar_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT search_ar_product_id_locale_key UNIQUE (product_id),
)
TABLESPACE dbspace1
;
CREATE INDEX search_ar_product_id_idx ON search.ar USING btree (product_id);
CREATE INDEX search_ar_product_id_idx_ccnew ON search.ar USING btree (product_id);
CREATE INDEX search_ar_product_id_idx_ccnew1 ON search.ar USING btree (product_id);
CREATE INDEX search_ar_product_id_idx_ccnew2 ON search.ar USING btree (product_id);
CREATE INDEX search_ar_product_id_idx_ccnew3 ON search.ar USING btree (product_id);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX search_ar_product_id_locale_key_ccnew ON search.ar USING btree (product_id);


What is the status of these indexes? Check SELECT indisvalid      , relname FROM pg_index     JOIN pg_catalog.pg_class pc ON pg_index.indexrelid = pc.oid; When indisvalid is false, creating the index has failed and you can remove it. This might happen when using CONCURRENTLY

If you use CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY, PostgreSQL will always create these indexes. It is the incomplete index that is being created. When PostgreSQL is done creating the index, it will be renamed to its final name.
If CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY fails, the index is left behind, and you have to drop it manually. This is necessary, because the statement is not running in a single database transaction to avoid locking the table.

Thanks for the explanation! Is there any way to instruct postgres to remove these indexes if the create index operation has failed ? Or at least to clean them up, right before a new reindex request is received. From what I can see, being left behind, they seem to do more harm than good.

No. If that were possible, PostgreSQL would do it. They are just dead weight.

Technically speaking, I don't see how that will be impossible to do at Postgres level... If I can manually remove them, Postgres should be able to track and remove them too IMO.

Yes, we could write a background job that patrols the database and regularly drops invalid indexes. But that seems excessive. I don't think that idea would meet with a lot of love.

How about creating these temporary indexes in some kind of  a "temp" folder and only associate/move/rename them to the parent table at the very end if everything is ok ? And during every postgres restart, clean up this "temp" folder. Will this be feasible ?

I don't think that a special directory will help. Dropping an index is more than just removing a file. For one, it will lock the table. Again, that would be a background job that does that. That will take a while. You may be willing to pay that price at every server start, but I am not certain if everybody would. You can discuss this on the pgsql-hackers list, that's the place for that.
